# MissingOptionalLibraryError: "The 'pdflatex' library is required to use 'LaTeX circuit drawing'

Tags: qiskit, quantum-circuit

Trying to run the below code block in a jupyter notebook in Windows 10:

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
import pdflatex
qc = QuantumCircuit(2)
qc.cx(0,1)
qc.draw('latex')
```

I have installed `pdflatex`. Line `import pdflatex` can be executed. But line `qc.draw()` raises `MissingOptionalLibraryError: "The 'pdflatex' library is required to use 'LaTeX circuit drawing'`.

[image: pip install pdflatex]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about quantum computing.